# ImageMagick change all images to preset size with DPI

Tags: imagemagick

Trying to use imagemagick to have all images set to a preset size like a letterhead (8 1/2x11) for example... id prefer to not use resize and trying to get them to a 100 dpi setting... Im personally not very good with imagemagick and after 2 days of searching around Ive got it mostly complete?

```
for f in `ls *jpg`; do 
   convert -compress Group4 -type bilevel \
           -depth 100 -units PixelsPerInch \
           -monochrome -resize 850X1100 $f 2-$f;
done
```

Anyone have any further pointers on this?

Answer (score 1):

You would use [-density](http://www.imagemagick.org/ImageMagick-7.0.0/script/command-line-options.php#density) option to set the DPI.

```sh
for f in `ls *jpg`
do 
  convert -compress Group4 \
          -type bilevel \
          -depth 100 \
          -units PixelsPerInch 
          -monochrome \
          -resize 850X1100 \
          -density 100 \
          $f 2-$f
done
```

You can verify by using the identify utility.

```sh
identify -format "%x x %y" some_image.jpg
```

### Edit:

As Birei pointed out. You can use "`*.jpg`" wildcard to iterate over the files in a directory, and quoting the output file name would be important for file names with spaces. You can use [Filename Percent Escapes](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/files/#save_escapes) to create & preserve source image information.

```sh
convert *.jpg \
        -compress Group4 \
        -type bilevel \
        -depth 100 \
        -units PixelsPerInch 
        -monochrome \
        -resize 850X1100 \
        -density 100 \
        -set filename:f '%f' \
        '2-%[filename:f]'
```

The `-set filename:f '%f'` will preserver the original file name w/ proper escaping, and `'2-%[filename:f]'` will write the 'f' value with custom prefix '2-'. No need to use Bash for-loop.

Comment: Better `*jpg` instead of the command substitution `\`ls *jpg\``. And also double quote all uses of the variable `$f` to avoid word splitting.

Comment: Good point. There doesn't appear to be any reason to use `ls *jpg` -- outside of preserving filename.